# get all ways by using esy-osmfilter

Tags: python, osmfilter

I have a pbf file, made with

```
`osmconvert64 --drop-relations "{}" -B="{}" -o="{}"'.\
                        format(input_osm, poly_file, output_osm)`
```

however I do not know how to retrieve only the ways from this file.
I have tried with esy-osmfilter, however I cannot imagine what to put in the Elements tag

```
PBF_inputfile = output_osm
JSON_outputfile = "{}\\{}.geojson".format(user_input.output, city)
prefilter = {Node: {}, Way: {"highway": ["motorway", "motorway_link", "trunk", "trunk_link"], },
                             Relation: {}}
whitefilter = []
blackfilter = []
[Data, _] = run_filter('highway', PBF_inputfile, JSON_outputfile, prefilter, whitefilter,
                                       blackfilter, NewPreFilterData=True, CreateElements=False,
                                       LoadElements=False,verbose=True)
[_, Elements] = run_filter('all_ways', PBF_inputfile, JSON_outputfile, prefilter, whitefilter,
                                           blackfilter, NewPreFilterData=False, CreateElements=True,
                                           LoadElements=False, verbose=True)

export_geojson(Elements['all_ways']['Way'], Data,
                               filename=JSON_outputfile, jsontype='Line')
```

I get an error:

> ERROR:esy.osmfilter.osm_filter:Warning2: whitefilter is not a list of list of tuples

I probably need to set whitefilter and blackfilter, but I do not know how to use them. I could not understand from the examples [here](https://pypi.org/project/esy-osmfilter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just follow the [dokumentation](https://dlr-ve-esy.gitlab.io/esy-osmfilter/filter.html)
than something like this should do the magic:

[(("highway","motorway"),),
(("highway","motorway_link"),),
.
.
]